# Unknown opcodes in spidermonkey's bytecode

Tags: firefox, spidermonkey

I've been checking out spidermonkey's bytecode for an academic research. I got the bytecodes list from this file: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jsopcode.tbl#106.

When I started to check out websites, and go over their bytecodes, I noticed that there are a at least three opcodes that are not in the tbl file: 236, 240, 235 (that's what I found this far).

Doesn't anyone know what they mean, or when can I find a more complete tbl file ???

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SpiderMonkey version doesn't match the code you are looking at. `mozilla-central` currently corresponds to Firefox 9. Your SpiderMonkey version most likely corresponds to the current release version however (Firefox 6). If you look at the file in the `mozilla-release` repository you will see the "additional" opcodes: http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/file/FIREFOX_6_0_RELEASE/js/src/jsopcode.tbl#l604

Comment: Firefox 6 is the latest **stable** version. The development continues however and either Firefox 8 or Firefox 9 will remove the opcodes you mention.